# Using will/will not after if

Tags: grammar, conditionals, clauses, future

Most grammar rules state that **will** shouldn't be used after **if**.

Here is my sentence, I am wondering whether it is correct.

> It may cause an exception if there won't be a valid character in the
>   stream.

Is this sentence correct? Or I should use **if there is no valid**?

Thanks

Comment: It may help to add a tag for a particular brand of English (eg "american-english", "british-english" or wherever). Some dialects which appear to be standard admit *would* there; others don't.

Answer (score -1):

Use "It may cause an exception if there is no valid character in the stream". You only use "will" in a conditional clause if the action in the clause takes place after the action in the main clause. In your example, the presence or absence of a valid character occurs before the exception.

That rule is generally applicable, but there are other cases where using will is appropriate, like when it's being used to express willingness, rather than future action.